# preg_match and replace function

Tags: php, replace

I would like your help with with preg_match and replace function I have this:

```
$replacement="NEW TEXT";
<p data-edit="1">TEXT A</p>
<div data-edit="2">TEXT B</div>
```

And I need to find div or p or anything with data-edit attribute that equals to some number, in this case for example 1 and replace the text inside for $replacement.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use `DOMDocument` or [`simple-html-dom`](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html)

Comment: I have to use preg_match and replace

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Then show what you tried. You should be able to use a capture group to capture the tags, then copy that to the replacement around `$replacement`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes I red this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and come up with the following: if (preg_match('/(data-edit)/', $mytext, $match)) { that finds me every data-id, when I tried if (preg_match('/(data-edit="1")/', $mytext, $match)) { and it gives error...

Comment: Please edit your post with what you tried, don't use the comments for that

Comment: "it gives error" - On this site, and when working with other developers, don't just say that, tell us the very specific error you are getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initiate by setting the HTML content and the text intended for replacement, identify the specific number within the '`data-edit`' attribute targeting, and employ a regular expression to isolate the complete HTML element. This process involves capturing both the opening and closing tags, particularly pinpointing elements with a '`data-edit`' attribute corresponding to the target number. Then utilize '`preg_replace_callback`' to invoke a callback function, crafting the replacement string and substituting the original element content with the newly defined text. Hope it helps.

```
<?php

$replacement = "NEW TEXT";
$htmlContent = '
<p data-edit="1">TEXT A</p>
<div data-edit="2">TEXT B</div>
';

$targetNumber = 1;

$pattern = '/(<(p|div|any other tag)[^>]*data-edit="\s*' . preg_quote($targetNumber, '/') . '\s*"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\2>)/i';

$newContent = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($replacement) {
    return $matches[1] . $replacement . $matches[4];
}, $htmlContent);

// Output the new content
echo $newContent;
?>
```

Comment: First, [`preg_replace_callback()` is overkill](https://3v4l.org/oDGN2). Second, it is unreliable to use `preg_` functions to parse HTML. Future headaches occur when the HTML input has deviations in quoting, attribute prefixes, whitespace anomalies, textual anomalies that _resemble_ HTML, and case-sensitivity issues.  Many developers have gone down the the regex path for HTML parsing; eventually we all learn that DOM parsers are the more reliable tools.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not reliable tools for parsing HTML.  It is best practice to leverage a legitimate HTML parser.  In this case, I find a combination of DomDocument and XPath to be a very direct approach.  Because your HTML doesn't have a (expected) parent element, I'll manually add a parent `div` tag and then removed it when stringifying the result.

The XPath query says at any depth in the document (`//`), match any element (`*`) with the attribute `data-edit` (`[@data-edit]`).  To target a specific `data-edit` value, write like `//*[@data-edit=2]`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IFPIG))

```
$replacement = 'NEW TEXT';
$html = <<<HTML
<p data-edit="1">TEXT A</p>
<div not-data-edit="3">TEXT C</div>
<div data-edit="2">TEXT B</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@data-edit]") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = $replacement;
}
var_export(substr($dom->saveHTML() ,5, -7));
```

Notice in my demo that the code perfectly differentiates between qualified/disqualified `data-edit` attributes.

```
'<p data-edit="1">NEW TEXT</p>
<div not-data-edit="3">TEXT C</div>
<div data-edit="2">NEW TEXT</div>'
```

Regex has to go to greater effort to safeguard against fringe cases.

Here is a somewhat related answer with similar insights: [preg_replace img src to data-src stack overflow (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546006/2943403)

---

More specifically about designating a `data-edit` number in the query, write as the following for `2`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/3qBWI)

```
$replacement = 'NEW TEXT';
$dataEditNumber = 2;
$html = <<<HTML
<p data-edit="1">TEXT A</p>
<div not-data-edit="2">TEXT C</div>
<div data-edit="2">TEXT B</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@data-edit=$dataEditNumber]") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = $replacement;
}
var_export(substr($dom->saveHTML() ,5, -7));
```